# "Subject/verb inversion after certain adverbs" Is there a situation where it's mandatory that we do it?

Tags: gramática, advérbios

In English, we sometimes begin a sentence with certain negative adverbs (hardly, little, never, etc) or adverbial phrases (only then, no sooner, etc) for emphasis.  The adverb thus placed requires that we use an inversion, i.e. put the verb before the subject, and it would be grammatically wrong not to do so.
The Portuguese language also admits of such an inversion but it’s not clear to me **whether it is mandatory** that we invert subject/verb position.  For example, “Jamais diria eu uma coisa dessas” can also be phrased as “Eu jamais diria uma coisa dessas” and both sentences are grammatically correct, though one of them sounds formal and more emphatic. 
And my question is:  Do we have a situation in Portuguese where not to invert would be wrong in the formal register?

Comment: Jamais eu diria "Jamais diria eu" essa inversão do verbo com o sujeito nem sempre soa bem.

Comment: @AndréLyra   I've said "Jamais diria eu uma coisa dessas." before,  out of sheer irony, sometimes laughing.

Comment: É Preciso observar a pontuação, quem é o sujeito e o predicado, os tipo de sujeito e de predicado e o que define e suas partes, qual o tipo de oração, etc, para entender como montar a frases fora de ordem. No geral, pontuar bem é o mais importante "Uma coisa dessas, eu jamais diria", "Eu, uma coisa dessas, jamais diria",

Comment: Uma outra forma de inversão relativamente comum em pt-BR é "Ouça isso: **estava eu** quieto no meu canto quando..."

Comment: A sintaxe portuguesa é bem livre quanto ao posicionamento de adjuntos adverbiais. As únicas restrições são semânticas ou prosódicas, quando a frase soa estranha, ainda que sintaticamente seja uma construção válida. E isso não afeta a posição do sujeito; ambos os elementos podem ser reposicionados separadamente. *"Eu jamais diria uma coisa dessas"*, *"Jamais eu diria uma coisa dessas"*, *"Eu diria jamais uma coisa dessas"*, e *"Eu diria uma coisa dessas jamais"* são todos gramaticalmente corretos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha, regra geral, o sujeito vem antes do verbo. Outros posicionamentos são em geral possíveis, mas ou têm uma ênfase diferenciada, ou soam literários.

Um adjunto adverbial alçado não muda isso:

> Jamais eu diria uma coisa dessas.
>
> ? Jamais diria eu uma coisa dessas. (puxando para o literário)

A principal exceção à regra são os sujeitos oracionais, que em geral vêm depois do verbo:

> É preciso que eu vá ao banco.

É comum também em frases feitas, do tipo "digo eu", "penso eu", onde serve para marcar uma ênfase, digamos, "pomposa":

> O Grêmio não perde para o Botafogo quarta-feira nem jogando com o time reserva, digo eu.

(Ou seja, quando digo que o Grêmio não perde para o Botafogo quarta-feira, estou falando muito sério.)

No caso específico, o alçamento do advérbio não muda muita coisa - ele já é enfático por si mesmo:

> Eu jamais diria uma coisa dessas.
>
> Jamais eu diria uma coisas dessas.
>
> Jamais diria eu uma coisa dessas.

Todas as construções são aceitáveis, mas só a primeira é trivial; as outras levarão o interlocutor a crer que você está querendo enfatizar a sua recusa em dizer uma coisa dessas, ou que você está brincando com as palavras.

Portanto, não: ao contrário do inglês, a inversão de posição entre verbo e sujeito após adjunto adverbial alçado não é obrigatória em Português.

Comment: Porque dizemos "estava eu" como em "estava eu quieto no meu canto quando...."  O objetivo seria enfatizar?  Ou seria uma forma unusual de se iniciar uma narrativa e que tornou-se idiomática?